# TO_NUMBER() Function In Oracle Behaves Differently

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have string variables and these variables differ in length. Let's assume that I have the following strings:

```
23.2
89.78
7895.369
7.2398539
0.1
```

I want to convert my string variables to float. So, to do that, I call TO_NUMBER() function. The problem is when I call TO_NUMBER() function from my .NET web application instead of calling it directly within pl/sql block, it gives me an "invalid number" error.

I want to be able to call TO_NUMBER() function from both my web application and within pl/sql block at the same time. Because it is in a stored procedure. I think that is something about NLS Parameters. But I couldn't make it work.

To sum up:

TO_NUMBER(string) syntax works fine if I call the function within PL/SQL block. But it gives me an "invalid number" error when I call it from my web application.

I want the exact value in float data type.

Comment: If this works fine in Oracle, I suspect the problem is in the .NET side. You're either passing variables incorrectly or they don't really contain what you think they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also want to call TO_NUMBER with the right NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER settings to avoid conflicts between your application side and your database side

```
23.2
89.78
7895.369
7.2398539
0.1
```

Then

```
SQL> with my_numbers as
  2  (
select 23.2        as c1 from dual union all
  3    4  select 89.78       as c1 from dual union all
select 7895.369    as c1 from dual union all
select 7.2398539   as c1 from dual union all
select 0.1         as c1 from dual
  5    6    7    8  ) select to_number ( c1 , '99999999999999D99999999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''' ) as result
from my_numbers ;  9

    RESULT
----------
      23.2
     89.78
  7895.369
 7.2398539
        .1
```

If you believe you might have no number, use @Gordon Linoff answer to look for non numeric values.

With different NLS settings

```
SQL> with my_numbers as
(
select 23.2        as c1 from dual union all
select 89.78       as c1 from dual union all
select 7895.369    as c1 from dual union all
select 7.2398539   as c1 from dual union all
select 0.1         as c1 from dual
) select to_number ( c1 , '99999999999999D99999999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''' ) as result
from my_numbers ;  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9

    RESULT
----------
       232
      8978
   7895369
  72398539
         1
```

Comment: Roberto, now I have another problem. I have the following strings:

'1.3655604E7',
'8.339313646E9',
'6.442450944E9'

When I try to convert them to float as you mentioned, Oracle still gives me an "invalid number" error. Is there a trick for 'E' letter?

Comment: indeed it is. That is scientific notation. You need for those to use the clause EEEE in to number, like this  `select to_number('2.44705130197009E18','9.99999999999999999999EEEE') as res from dual` The output of this is: `2.4471E+18`

Answer (score 0):

The numbers that you have shown are all valid and work fine with `to_number()` (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3af73c1ae92dbfc2834d404f7493da8a)).

I am guessing that you have bad data.  Use regular expressions to find it:

```
select col
from t
where not regexp_like(col, '^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$')
```

Comment: It works if replace the dots with commas. But this time, I can't call TO_NUMBER(string) within PL/SQL block. 

TO_NUMBER(REPLACE('1.2', '.', ','))

Comment: @Tayfun That's either your .NET application setting its own NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS or relying on a default value that's not the one you need.

Comment: Yes, it seems my .NET application is setting its own NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS.